# Sorting Series Data on an RDLC Bar Chart

Tags: visual-studio, sorting, reporting, rdlc

I have a list of objects that are sorted by a percentage value in ascending order. Then when I right-click on the bars and under the series data value field, I enter the following expression:

**=FormatNumber(Avg(Fields!Percentage.Value),2)**

Attached is an image of the chart. I would like to sort the bars in ascending order for each Milestone Phase. How can I do this? It appeared to be working before but I'm not quite sure what happened that caused it to not work anymore. Perhaps before I only had one value per contact and the average was the percentage since there was only one percentage to average out. Not quite sure but I can't seem to find out how to fix this.

I've selected the Series Group Properties, set the Group Expression to Group on ContactName and then changed the Sorting expression to =Avg(Fields!Percentage.Value) but this does not sort the bars in any order whatsoever so I'm not quite sure what to do next.

[image]